# Finding a basis of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a bit of difficulty finding the basis of  kernel given a matrix. The matrix is a 2x4 matrix with entries (-9 -3 -3 3) (-9 -3 -3 3) which I then put into rref as (1 1/3 1/3 -1/3) (0 0 0 0).

I then looked at this as the solution to the equation Ax = 0 so I wrote out w+1/3x+1/3y-1/3z, but I'm unsure how to go about this now. I know that I have to express the variables in terms of one another but just confused as to exactly how to do this...any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The procedure that is usually taught is to write the "pivot" entry in terms of the "free" entries. You have $w+\frac{1}{3} x + \frac{1}{3} y - \frac{1}{3}z=0$, so the solutions are of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w \\ x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{3} x - \frac{1}{3} y + \frac{1}{3}z \\ x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
=x \begin{bmatrix}
-1/3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ y \begin{bmatrix}
-1/3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ z \begin{bmatrix}
1/3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Those three vectors are a basis for the kernel.